# Refresh content of the dropdown based on result

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown, bootstrap-table

I am trying to develop an Excel-like table filter where any number of filters can be applied across columns.

Please have a look at my [code in plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nb2Ed8xYt12WpVkblZC1?p=preview). This works perfectly fine for the filtering of data. But I want the "filter" list to be updated when data is updated. I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

```
.filter('inArray', function($filter){
return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
    if(arrayFilter){
        return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
            return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
        });
    }
};
```

});

For example (from plunkr):
If we select "India", it will return 3 records having Month 2,3 and 7. I want the Month filter list to display the values from the result (2,3,7) instead of showing all the values.
Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: What do you mean the Severity option should "open records"?  I'm not understanding what is supposed to happen here.  The filters are working correctly in your Plunker, what do you want it to do next?

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Some issue with Stackoverflow auto-edit. I explained what exactly I want. Please help me to fix this. @RaniRadcliff

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a complete "hack" and I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this will at least give you a work around.  I forked your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XQzYmxQ43tMILOgxMfNk?p=preview) and made a few changes.  I added an `ng-change` on your countries list to show or hide the filtered months:

```
                                <div class="dt-buttons btn-group">
                                    Selected Countries:<br>
                                    <select size="4" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCountries" ng-options="country for country in countryList" ng-change="filterMonths()"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-show="!countryselected" class="dt-buttons btn-group">
                                    Selected Months:<br>
                                    <select size="10" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedMonths" ng-options="month for month in monthList"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-show="countryselected" class="dt-buttons btn-group">
                                    Selected Months:<br>
                                    <select size="10" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="monthsSelected"><option ng-repeat="f in filtered">{{f.month}}</option></select>
                                </div>
```

Then in the controller, I added:

```
    $scope.countryselected = false;
$scope.filterMonths = function(){
  $scope.countryselected = true;
}
```

If I think of a better way, I'll edit my answer, but this should at least get you going.  Good luck!